# HTML text area not displaying with placeholder

Tags: html, placeholder

When I render the webpage, the input field displays the placeholder "enter key word" but the textarea does not display the placeholder. Where am I going wrong?

```html
 <div>
        <textarea id="paragraph" rows="5" cols="35" placeholder="Enter the paragraph here..." value = ''>
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="word" placeholder="Enter the keyword here..." value="">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
<div>
    <textarea id="paragraph" rows="5" cols="35" placeholder="Enter the paragraph here..." value = ''>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div>
    <textarea id="paragraph" rows="5" cols="35" placeholder="Enter the paragraph here..." value = ''></textarea>
</div>
```

The text area is taking blank spaces as values since there is space before the closing tag

Comment: Glad i could help. Keep coding!